# Metadata column update using client object model in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am working on Sharepoint 2013 site, I need to manually add value to metadata column "Network" in Library "Drop Off Library". I check if a particular word in present in the document and then I try to update the item. When I try updating "Network" column and other Choice column "PickUp". My metadata column does not get updated but Choice Column gets updated.
Below is my code. Please note I am using CSOM.

```
foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in ItemCol)
                {
foreach(Term Tstring in termColl)
                        {
                            object findText = Tstring.Name;
                            word.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
                            if (word.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                ref missing, ref missing))
                            {

                                item.File.CheckOut();
                                item["Network"] = "3;#Cartoon"; //My term:cartoon with 3 as term id(checked in TaxonomyHiddenList)
        item["PickUp"] = "Yes";
                                item.Update();
                                context.Load(item);
                                lists.Update();
                                context.ExecuteQuery();
                                item.File.CheckIn("Done", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using below code

```
if (word.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                ref missing, ref missing))
                            {
item.File.CheckOut();
                                    TaxonomyFieldValue termValue = null;
                                    TaxonomyField txField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(lists.Fields.GetByTitle("Network"));
                                    termValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue();
                                    termValue.Label = Tstring.Name;
                                    termValue.TermGuid = Tstring.Id.ToString();
                                    termValue.WssId = -1;
                                    txField.SetFieldValueByValue(item, termValue);
                                    item["GetMetadata"] = "Yes";
                                    item.Update();
                                    item.File.CheckIn("Done", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                                    context.Load(item);
                                    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```